# Input 2D array from JSON to Unity

Tags: json, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, wrapper

I am trying to load a json file to unity, everything works fine until i try to load a 2D array. 
My json file is in this form:

```
"name": "Group 1",
"ID": 0,
"Components": 8,
"RelationArray": [
  [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ]
]
```

I am currently using JsonHelper as a wrapper

```
public class JsonHelper
{


    public static T[] FromJson<T>(string json)
    {
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = UnityEngine.JsonUtility.FromJson<Wrapper<T>>(json);
        Debug.Log(wrapper.Objects);
        return wrapper.Objects;


    }

    public static string ToJson<T>(T[] array)
    {
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = new Wrapper<T>();
        wrapper.Objects = array;
        return UnityEngine.JsonUtility.ToJson(wrapper);
    }

    [Serializable]
    private class Wrapper<T>
    {
        public T[] Objects;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if your string is in valid json format?

Strings in json format are surrounded by "{ }".

Good way to check is to throw it in online json parser like http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try using Newtonsoft.Json. I find it the best to work with. Here's an example:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // this is just a string escaped version of your json that you linked.  
        // You should have something like this in code by the time you want to deserialize it.
        var jsonString = "{\r\n\t\"name\": \"Group 1\",\r\n\t\"ID\": 0,\r\n\t\"Components\": 8,\r\n\t\"RelationArray\": [\r\n\t\t[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],\r\n\t\t[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],\r\n\t\t[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],\r\n\t\t[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],\r\n\t\t[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],\r\n\t\t[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],\r\n\t\t[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],\r\n\t\t[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]\r\n\t]\r\n}";

        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObject>(jsonString);
        Console.WriteLine(obj.name);
        Console.WriteLine(obj.ID);
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Components);
        for(int i = 0; i < obj.RelationArray.Length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < obj.RelationArray[i].Length; j++){
                Console.Write(obj.RelationArray[i][j] + ", ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    // make a class to deserialize your json string into
    class YourObject {
        public String name;
        public int ID;
        public int Components;
        public int[][] RelationArray;
    }   
}
```

The result written to the console:

```
Group 1
0
8
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
```

Comment: Thank you seems straight frwrd, very helpful. what if i have a series of objects in my json file how i will syntax it. Currently i use this class: 

[Serializable]
public class Tasks
{

    public string name;
    public int ID;
    public int Components;  
    public int[] RelationArray;


    public Tasks(string NewName, int newID, int newCompo,  newRelationArray)
    {
        name = NewName;
        ID = newID;
        Components = newCompo;
        RelationArray = newRelationArray;
    }

}

Comment: you probably wouldn't have a series of objects in a json file loosely, there should be one root object, that can then have many child objects inside it.  let's say your json was like { multipleobjects: [ object:{ "name"="object1"  }, object:{"name"="object2"} ] }        Then you would deserialize your json file into the root node type (a class called multipleobjects with an array of object)